# Burn Enable button on check box check

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix

I am developing the installer in wix using Burn.I an using the default `Bootstraper Application` to bundle `msi` and using   hyperlink license and customized the default theme.I use empty space for `LicenseUrl` to hide the hyperlink license screen.

```
 <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" ThemeFile="HyperlinkTheme.xml" LocalizationFile="HyperlinkTheme.wxl"  LogoFile="D:\..\ym_header3.jpg"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

I have created a check box in welcome screen as below,

```
<Checkbox Name="InstallCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-41" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" >I am running this as Administrator</Checkbox>
```

I want to disable the `install` button initially.If the user check this check box then i need to enable the `Install` button.Again if they uncheck the check box i need to disable the `Install` button.How to do this in wix or bundle.

Answer (score 0):

[`WixStandardBootstrapperApplication`](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp) today doesn't support custom logic like this in general, but you can use its limited functionality here.  You need the `EulaHyperlink` and `EulaAcceptCheckbox` controls (they must be named that way) in your theme:

```
<Hypertext Name="EulaHyperlink" X="11" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="51"
           TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes" />
<Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-41" Width="260"
          Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">
    #(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)
</Checkbox>
```

Note that there is no text for `EulaHyperlink`, which effectively hides it.  You also need to specify something for the `LicenseUrl` even though it won't be shown:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication ThemeFile="HyperlinkThemeCustomized.xml"
   LicenseUrl="http://link.net" LocalizationFile="HyperlinkThemeCustomized.wxl" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

The `EulaAcceptCheckbox` is the checkbox that will control whether the `InstallButton` is enabled.

Comment: Being a long term fan of wix for building MSI packages, it's sad to say that my experience with burn has been a succession of disapointments...